# Pandas - Merge two data frames, create new column, append values to array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to merge two data frames on the same `id` in each dataframe, but to create a new column and append any values in a specified column to an array in the new dataframe column. I would expect to see multiple matching ids in the second data frame.

Here is an example to clarify what I am looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(5, 4)), columns=('ID', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3'))
print(df1)

   ID  X1  X2  X3
0   1   1   0   2
1   0   1   0   1
2   0   1   2   2
3   1   2   2   0
4   2   1   0   0

d = {'ID' : pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 4, 5]), 'Tag' : pd.Series(['One', 'Two', 'Two', 'Four', 'Five'])}
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(d))
print(df2)

   ID   Tag
0   1   One
1   2   Two
2   1   Two
3   4  Four
4   5  Five
```

This is what I am expecting to see for the first row:

```
   ID  X1  X2  X3  Merged_Tags
0   1   1   0   2  ['One', 'Two']
```

I want to join on the `id` column of df1 by looking through all of df2 for matching `ids` (**there will be multiple matching ids**). When a matching `id` is found, the value stored in `df2['Tag']` should be appended to a column in df1, perhaps an array.

I managed this iteratively but my dataset is relativity large and so have not found it viable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
In [35]: pd.merge(df1, df2.groupby('ID').Tag.apply(list).reset_index(), on='ID', how='left')
Out[35]:
   ID  X1  X2  X3         Tag
0   2   1   1   2       [Two]
1   1   0   1   1  [One, Two]
2   0   2   1   2         NaN
3   1   0   2   2  [One, Two]
4   0   0   2   2         NaN
```

alternatively you can use `map()` method:

```
In [38]: df1['Merged_Tags'] = df1.ID.map(df2.groupby('ID').Tag.apply(list))

In [39]: df1
Out[39]:
   ID  X1  X2  X3 Merged_Tags
0   2   1   1   2       [Two]
1   1   0   1   1  [One, Two]
2   0   2   1   2         NaN
3   1   0   2   2  [One, Two]
4   0   0   2   2         NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the response MaxU - one more thing, is it possible to `groupby` `ID` and concat the tags to show the frequency. ie. `ID: 1` and the merged column `Merged_Tags: [One: 2, Two: 2]`

Comment: @user3939059, you are welcome. It's not quite clear - do you want to repeat the "counts" in each row? Can you post a desired data set or, better,  open a new question?

Comment: Created a new question to make things clearer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079415/data-frame-group-id-create-value-count-dictionary

Comment: @user3939059, OK, i'll take a look at it when i'll have some free time...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df1.join(df2.groupby('ID').Tag.apply(lambda group: list(group)), on='ID')

   ID  X1  X2  X3         Tag
0   1   1   0   2  [One, Two]
1   0   1   0   1         NaN
2   0   1   2   2         NaN
3   1   2   2   0  [One, Two]
4   2   1   0   0       [Two]
```