# Data frame group ID, create value: count in column

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following sample dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(5, 4)), columns=('ID', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3')))
print(df1)

   ID  X1  X2  X3
0   2   2   0   2
1   1   0   2   1
2   1   2   1   1
3   1   2   0   2
4   2   0   0   0

d = {'ID' : pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 4, 5]), 'Tag' : pd.Series(['One', 'Two', 'Two', 'Four', 'Five'])}
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(d))
print(df2)

   ID   Tag
0   1   One
1   2   Two
2   1   Two
3   4  Four
4   5  Five

df1['Merged_Tags'] = df1.ID.map(df2.groupby('ID').Tag.apply(list))
print(df1)

   ID  X1  X2  X3 Merged_Tags
0   2   2   0   2       [Two]
1   1   0   2   1  [One, Two]
2   1   2   1   1  [One, Two]
3   1   2   0   2  [One, Two]
4   2   0   0   0       [Two]
```

Expected output for `ID = 1`:

**1.**

How would one groupby each key and generate a `Tag: Frequency` format in the `Merged_Tags` column?

```
    ID  X1  X2  X3     Merged_Tags
1   1   0   2   1  [One: 3, Two: 3]
```

**2.**

Create a new column for the number of rows with that `ID`

```
    ID  X1  X2  X3      Merged_Tags  Frequency
1   1   0   2   1  [One: 3, Two: 3]      3
```

**3.**

Add the values of column `X3` in each row occurrence with the same `ID`

```
    ID  X1  X2  X3      Merged_Tags  Frequency  X3++
1   1   0   2   1  [One: 3, Two: 3]      3        4
```

Comment: there are different tags for the same id, but they are merged to the `Merged_Tags` column. Is that a problem?

Comment: sorry, i could not find any elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

```
1   0   2   1  [One: 3, Two: 3]
```

should be [One: 2, Two:3] instead right? Considering that:

```
  1 : [One,Two]
  0 : None
  2 : [Two]
  1 : [One, Two]
```

and you want a total counter of each key in the row ?

Please help me understand the intuition behind [One:3, Two:3] in case I am missing anything here, but your question should be easy to solve otherwise