# Python: searching through two data frames and when data matches append to new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames and I want to append the 'lat' and 'lon' column values when 'CommonName' column of first data frame matches the 'Name' column of the second data frame to the second data frame.

The first data frame is 'AllBusStops' and takes the form:

```
AllBusStops = {'CommonName': ['Cambuslang Road', 'Hillsborough Road'],'lon': [-4.17351, -4.12914], 'lat': [55.82932, 55.85388]}
```

The second data frame is 'SixtyOne' and takes the form:

```
SixtyOne = {'Name': ['Canonbie Street', 'Hillsborough Road']}
```

So in the above example the 'lat', 'lon' values from the AllBusStops dataframe would be appended to the SixtyOne data frame for Hillsborough Road.

The code looks like this thus far:

```
for i in range(len(AllBusStops)):
   for j in range(len(SixtyOne)):
        if AllBusStops[['CommonName']][i] == SixtyOne[['Name']][j]:
           Lat = AllBusStops[['Lat']][i]
           Lon = AllBusStops[['Lon']][i]
```

When I execute this I receive the following message:

```
KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data from your 2 dataframes with overlapping Name? See also [mcve].

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception you should always include the complete Traceback in the question. The `KeyError` means you are trying to access a label in a DataFrame that does not exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070329/pandas-merge-two-data-frames-create-new-column-append-values-to-array?rq=1

Comment: Hello, yes I can sorry about that. The BusStop dataframe has following column names: "ATCOCode", "Easting", "Northing", "Lon" ,"Lat" "CommonName","Street", "Landmark","Town". The SixtyOne data frame has following column name: "Name". When "CommonName" column from the BusStop dataframe is the same as "Name" column from SixtyOne data frame I want to append the "lat" and "lon" from BusStops dataframe to the corresponding row in the the SixtyOne data frame. I hope this is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on the structure of your data, but it sounds like you want to *merge* the data in two dataframes.  See the [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function.

This code will return a dataframe like `SixtyOne`, with 'Lat' and 'Lon' columns inserted.

```
# The value of the 'how' parameter depends on your needs; 
# see documentation for 'merge'

combined = SixtyOne.merge(AllBusStops[['CommonName', 'Lat', 'Lon']],
                          left_on='Name',
                          right_on'CommonName',
                          how='left')
```

As noted in the comment, you should read about the `how` parameter that that `merge` takes; if you are confused you can search online for phrases like "SQL left outer join".

The code above uses a *left join*, which is a little different than your code snippet.  But I suspect you actually want a left join in this case, e.g. so that you can observe records in `SixtyOne` that do not have a latitude and longitude value from the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Say your DataFrame looks like this:

```
d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

>>> df
   one  two
a  1.0  1.0
b  2.0  2.0
c  3.0  3.0
d  NaN  4.0
>>>
```

When you access columns like this (`AllBusStops[['CommonName']]`), it produces a DataFrame (You probably wanted a Series)

```
>>> z = df[['one']]
>>> type(z)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>> z
   one
a  1.0
b  2.0
c  3.0
d  NaN
>>>
```

Then you try to get the first item with an integer index (`AllBusStops[['CommonName']][i]`) which produces the KeyError - the DataFrame is expecting a label.

```
>>> z[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2442, in get_loc
...
KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#288>", line 1, in <module>
    z[0]
...
KeyError: 0
```

You can retrieve a Series by accessing the column like this

```
>>> q = df['one']
>>> type(q)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> q
a    1.0
b    2.0
c    3.0
d    NaN
Name: one, dtype: float64
>>>
```

Then retrieve the first item in the series

```
>>> q[0]
1.0
>>>
```

---

Notice that I made a simple DataFrame and tried to *mimic* your program's steps to see if I could reproduce the problem.  This is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (mcve) - you should read that. Sometimes making an mcve for yourself (or to post here) will illuminate the problem for you or make it easier to figure out yourself.
[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

---

As @NichloasM's answer mentions, you might want to explore merging/joining your dat.  Pandas has excellent documentation - [Merge, Join, and concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merge-join-and-concatenate)